# Matlab: Using "hold on" for histograms results in different bin width

Tags: matlab, histogram, visualization

I seem to have the strange problem that when I plot the following, the bars of the two histograms do not seem to have the same width:

```
hold on
[N,X] = hist(feature_1(:,1))
Bh = bar(X,N,'facecolor',[0.7 0.2 0.2]);
[A,Y] = hist(feature_2(:,1))
Bh = bar(Y,A,'facecolor',[0.3 0.6 0.2]);
hold off
```

Why is that?
Thanks

Edit: Sorry for not providing input.
For instance, `feature_1(:,1:5)` =

```
[0.72507334
0.019627856
0.19571847
-0.23818338
1.6526113
0.23925941
0.69914567
0.15934853
0.28082907
-0.035707321
0.072205774
-0.15791744
0.81654513
0.19398287
-0.33666527
-0.24295111
-1.0770919
-1.2977802
0.67290813
-0.56841594
-0.28522778
-2.2450733
-1.4413888
-2.2216258
-0.46346179
1.8239603
1.6443830
1.3715266
0.34339836
-0.29903534]
```

and `feature_2(:,1)` =

```
[0.18098037
-0.81469119
-0.086869463
-0.67799056
1.1408544
1.2589806
1.0065788
0.64472252
-0.70849174
0.69045025
-0.0031675443
-0.82824785
0.15744546
-0.028384065
-0.065391541
-0.35754660
-1.0809286
-0.12427557
1.3792992
-0.28740802
1.7593855
-1.2061185
-3.0156419
-1.1680259
0.23381938
0.97127295
0.91487378
0.83101124
0.24949571
-0.96599007]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MATLAB suggests](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/replace-discouraged-instances-of-hist-and-histc.html) you use `histogram()` instead of `hist()`.

If I had to guess why your bars are of different widths, it would be because you have different numbers of bins for each histogram, though don't take my word for it. (It also could be a stylistic thing, where the bars are offset so that you can see both colors, as `hist()` does not blend like `histogram()` does.)

You can solve the width problem by specifying the width using `histogram()`:

```
histogram(feature_1(:,1:5),'BinWidth',.5);
hold on 
histogram(feature_2(:,1),'BinWidth',.5);
```

If you run this code, you'll be able to see the differences in plotting styles:

```
subplot(2,1,1)
hold on
[N,X] = hist(feature_1(:,1:5));
Bh = bar(X,N,'facecolor',[0.7 0.2 0.2]);
[A,Y] = hist(feature_2(:,1));
Bh = bar(Y,A,'facecolor',[0.3 0.6 0.2]);

subplot(2,1,2)
histogram(feature_1(:,1:5),'BinWidth',.5,'FaceColor','r');
hold on 
histogram(feature_2(:,1),'BinWidth',.5,'FaceColor','g');
```

Hope this helped somewhat!

Comment: somewhat? more like absolutely awesome answer:)! thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I don't get the purpose but width is same for both, the bins are different. If you want to show both in a same figure for comparison purpose, then you must adapt this way

```
bar([X',Y'])
xlable('-->No of bins')
legend('Feature1','Feature2')
```